# Tinymce autocomplete list not formatting correctly

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using tinymce, with an autocompleter, but it's not displaying correctly and we cannot read the values.

[image]

Here is my code inside the `tinymce.init`

```
       setup: function (editor) {
            /* An autocompleter that allows you to insert special characters */
            editor.ui.registry.addAutocompleter('text_responses', {
              ch: '/',
              minChars: 1,
              columns: 'auto',
              fetch: function (pattern) {
                var matchedChars = text_responses.filter(function (char) {
                  return char.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
                });
                
                return new tinymce.util.Promise(function (resolve) {
                  var results = matchedChars.map(function (char) {
                    return {
                      value: char.replacement,
                      text: char.display,
                      icon: char.display
                    }
                  });
                  resolve(results);
                });
              },
              onAction: function (autocompleteApi, rng, value) {
                editor.selection.setRng(rng);
                editor.insertContent(value);
                autocompleteApi.hide();
              }
            });
        }
```